# Why won't my z-index div with the highest number display over others? [JSFiddle]

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center and fix an input box on the top of the page. I set the `z-index` so it appears above the navigation bar. To center it I surrounded it with a `div`. However, this makes the links unclickable. I tried to set the `z-index` on the inner `div` only which contains the `input` field, but then it disappears under the navigation bar! Why can't I set the `z-index` on the `.top-search` `div` so it appears on top, while the surrounding `.top-search-banner` `div` is left on the bottom? I tried setting `position: relative;` on the inner `div` but that didn't help. I tried using `<center>` but that didn't help. I tried setting `z-index` on the `input` field itself, but that didn't help. I tried setting `z-index` on the logo and links themselves, to `1050`, but that didn't help. I can't insert the form into the banner because the banner is part of the layout, and the form only shows on one page. I can't use `left: 50px;` because it has to be responsive for different screen sizes, hence centered. Here is a JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/f1cp6bg3/8/

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1030;
  top: 0px;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
}
.links {
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
}
.top-search-banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: 1040;
  /*if commented, input is hidden, despite zindex=1050 */
  width: 100%;
}
.top-search {
  position: relative;
  /* this doesn't help */
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1050;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <!-- Links are unclickable due to .top-search-banner -->
  <a href="/">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </a>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="top-search-banner">
  <div class="top-search">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Chloe — Exactly. Put the question in the question. Don't hide half of it on a third party site

Comment: You can remove `position:fixed` from `.top-search-banner` should get the links working

Comment: @Chloe instead of my earlier comment keep the `position:fixed` remove the `width:100%` and add a `left:80px` should do it.

Comment: @Corporalis That does work, but then it is no longer fixed and disappears when you scroll. https://jsfiddle.net/f1cp6bg3/7/ That wasn't obvious so I updated the question.

Comment: @Chloe what about the second comment? Sorry I'm on a tablet at the minute

Comment: @Corporalis That does work for the fiddle, but is there no way to center it? The designer set a bunch of media CSS breakpoints to dynamically change the size of the box as the screen shrinks. A fixed left side doesn't always line up with all sizes. That should work in the interim. Thanks.

Comment: @Chloe How's [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6vojasLz/) I set the `width:60%` and `margin:auto 20%` on the `.top-search-banner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated solution with it outside the `<nav>`

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1030;
  top: 0px;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
}
.links{padding: 10px; float: right;}
.top-search-banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: 1040; /*if commented, input is hidden, despite zindex=1050 */
  width: 200px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
input {width: 100%;}
```

```html
<body>
<nav>
  <!-- Links are unclickable due to .top-search-banner -->
  <a href="/">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </a>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="top-search-banner">
    <input type="text">
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</body>
```

Essentially, I removed the second `<div>` and defined the width directly in `.top-search-banner`, gave it a left and right value of 0 as well a margin auto.

Comment: Is there no other way, to position and center the input on the page separately and independently from the nav?

Comment: This is so simple and ingenious! Why didn't I think of it?!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a height of 0px to the div, making it disappear

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1030;
  top: 0px;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
}
.links{padding: 10px; float: right;}
.top-search-banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: 1040; /*if commented, input is hidden, despite zindex=1050 */
  width: 100%;
  
}
.top-search {
  position: relative; /* this doesn't help */
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1050;
  height: 0px;  /* new */
}
input {width: 100%;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <!-- Links are unclickable due to .top-search-banner -->
  <a href="/">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </a>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="top-search-banner">
  <div class="top-search">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

Comment: Wow that's so simple, yet counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: relative;
```

should be on the parent element of nav and topsearch, for example the `body`.

```
.top-search {
  position: absolute; // or position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem, uncomment the z-index on top-search and the input is above the rest of the elements. put a background-color on the top-search and give it a height and width: 100%. Input should have a width of, for example 200px;.

Comment: It still doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/f1cp6bg3/9/ The input is not visible. What is the link to your solution?

Comment: I uncommented the z-index in your fiddle and it worked

Comment: But it covers the links! That's not a solution! That's the very problem I am here asking about!

Comment: then wrap the top-search in another element with position relative